# Python 3, how to break into pieces a string

Tags: python, python-3.8

I need to break a string of characters.
The substring must be composed:

1. first letter, no matter if vowel or consonant
2. All consonants
3. all vowels

example:
string: 'dipestaggio'
result: ['di', 'pe', 'sta', 'ggio']

string: 'odiattuazio'
result: ['o', 'dia', 'ttua', 'zio']

I tried with this code but it's wrong:

```
def separate(word):
    A = word[0]
    L = []
    for pre,cur in zip(word[2:], word[1:]):
      if cur in voc:
          A += cur       
      elif cur not in voc:
          L.append(A)
          if pre in voc: A = ''
          A += cur
    return L
```

Someone is strong with words?
Thanks

Comment: The examples provided are presumably outputs of the incorrect code(?).  Can you please update the question with 1) Explicit requirements, 2) example words, 3) expected output.  Thank you.

Comment: Instead of just saying "but this code is wrong", it would be much more helpful to provide the actual output produced by the code along with an explanation of exactly _what_ is wrong about it.

Comment: @S3DEV The examples are correct, nothing wrong.
@JohnGordon The current output is `['di', 'pe', 'pes', 'ta', 'tag']`
@mario-l just a few minutes an I'll provide the answer, need a bit of time

Comment: @LorenzoZane - How are you planning to build code around requirements which are vague, at best - and non-existent in reality?  If the (inconsistent) outputs are right, as you state (based on?); how do these match the stated (vague) requirements?

Comment: @S3DEV The requirements are not clear, I can't argue with that, but rereading couple of times we could understand what he are asking for.
The pattern for the substring, as far as I understand, must be: `a_letters + all_consonants + all_vocals`.
The only doubt I have is about dividing `o` and `dia` solving `odiattuazio`, @mario-l can you clarify that?

Comment: @LorenzoZane - Exactly.  Then, how can you post an answer based on unclear requirements ... and an absent / unresponsive OP?

Comment: @S3DEV This is how I interpreted the text after reading the requests a couple of times and I'm pretty sure I interpreted it well (hope so). I'm not saying things against what you're saying, but with the data and the requests we have so far, this is what we can come to. If mine is not the solution to Mario's problem he will update the question, so we can provide a more clear solution.
I write that code based on the correctness of my interpretation (if it's not, I apologize)

Comment: @S3DEV so far nothing I tried to add to mario's explanation goes against some specification. I updated the answer and corrected my doubt by adding a comment at the end. Nothing indicates that we (or I) are interpreting the request in the wrong way, if you find contradictions please tell me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible solution according to the information we have so far:

```
string = "dipestaggio"
voc = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]

def separate(word):
    A = ""
    L = []
    for letter in word:
        if len(A) < 1:
            A += letter
        else:
            if A[len(A) - 1] not in voc:
                A += letter
            else:
                if letter in voc:
                    A += letter
                else:
                    L.append(A)
                    A = letter
    L.append(A)
    return L
    
print(separate(string))
```

The **output** for `dipestaggio` will be:

```
['di', 'pe', 'sta', 'ggio']
```

**UPDATE:** if you want to concatenate consonants to vowels if the consonants it's the first letter, you can change `if len(A) < 1` to `if len(A) <= 1`

Comment: How and why do you conclude this is right? The requirements are vague and inconsistent.

Comment: @S3DEV I answered you above. This solution try to match all the requests that we have (could be more detailed obviously)... I'm just trying to help

Comment: I apologies if I was not clear but the @LorenzoZane solution seems perfect. Thanks a lot!